# python: replace zeros by previous nonzero value

Tags: python

I would like to take a list of numbers in Python and replace all zeros by the previous nonzero value, e.g. `[1, 0, 0, 2, 0]` should give `[1,1,1,2,2]`. I know that the first entry in the list is nonzero so initialisation should not be a problem. I can do it in a loop but is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

To clarify: This should work on any numeric list, e.g. `[100.7, 0, -2.34]` should become `[100.7, 100.7, -2.34]`.

Comment: Close voter: Care to explain why you think it lacks information to answer the question? It seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: There's nothing unpythonic in a `for`-loop.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you solve it using a for-loop?

Comment: You just keep track of the last non zero element.

Comment: Actually, no need to keep track, `if a[i] == 0: a[i]=a[i-1]`, the last element is the one that should be set to in this case (assuming you can manipulate the original list, of course...)

Comment: of course, I was aiming for the OP to post the actual code...

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a quite short loop:

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0]
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i if i else b[-1])
print b
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Works only if there is a previous non-zero value (i.e. fails if a starts with 0).

As there is no way to reference a list comprehension from inside, this cannot be made a list comprension

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit mutable default arguments to avoid global or static variables to store the last none-zero element:

```
def val(x,z=[0]):
   if x:
     z[0] = x
   return z[0]

[val(x) for x in a]
```

Will yield, as expected `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]`

Comment: (I think it is the first time I actually intentionally used the mutable default arguments feature...)

Comment: Wow. I think this is worse than the solution that uses the global. I would not recommend it as it relies on semantics of the language that are usually only understood after being bitten by some truly confusing bugs.

Answer (score 2):

In 3.3, there's a one-liner using `accumulate`:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> seq = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0]
>>> list(accumulate(seq, lambda x,y: y if y else x))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
>>> seq = [100.7, 0, -2.34]
>>> list(accumulate(seq, lambda x,y: y if y else x))
[100.7, 100.7, -2.34]
```

(Could use `or` too, I guess, but I find the ternary easier to read.)

Comment: this should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended more than a simple, readable loop. But...

```
>>> my_list = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0]

>>> def set_sentinel(x):   
...     global sentinel
...     sentinel = x
...     return False
... 

>>> [set_sentinel(elem) or elem if elem else sentinel for elem in my_list]    
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you explicitly want to avoid a `for` loop, here is a one liner. But this is not as efficient as the loop.

```
>>> l = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0]
>>> [l[i] if l[i] else filter(lambda x: x > 0, l[:i])[-1] for i in range(len(l))]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

For every element which is zero, you are finding all non-zero elements upto that element, and fetching the last one.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of sounding trite.. No. Use a loop. I think it is the clearest way to express what you want.

```
for i in range(1, len(a)):
  if a[i] == 0:
    a[i] = a[i-1]
```

I have seen many atrocities committed in the name of being "Pythonic." Chose carefully based on what best expresses your intent. Don't try to blindly optimize for least lines of code or most clever implementation.

Comment: `enumerate` generates a tuple of `index, element`. Here I did not want the element directly, so it is less Pythonic to introduce a variable you do not intend to use.

Comment: you can remove the use of x by using a[i - 1] instead.

Comment: @njzk2 Edited to reflect your suggestion.